# C# datagridview shound not change until there is a result

Tags: c#

Recently i developed a search function, but i want when a user inputs something on the textbox the datagridview to not go blank but instead to show the data that it already has and when the result is found than only show the result. Because now when i type anything on the search textbox the dgv immediately goes blank.

Here is my code:

```
 private void txtBarkod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBarkod.Text)) {

            resetTxTboxes();

        }
        MySqlConnection connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();
        try {



            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
            DataTable tabela;



            string query = "SELECT * FROM artikli WHERE barcode  like '%" + txtBarkod.Text + "%'";
            command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            tabela = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(tabela);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;






            if (txtBarkod.Text == "") {

                ShowDgV();

            }




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            connection.Close();



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset/Rebind the datasource of your datagridview only if you found something in your db.

```
if(tabela.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
}
```